# Sending hex values with g_socket_send in C

Tags: c, glib

Is it possible in C to send a hex value via UDP, through a GSocket using g_socket_send? I don't necessarily need to do any conversions one way or the other, but even when I manually enter a hex string as the gchar buffer in g_socket_send, it is sent as an ASCII string.

Thank you in advance!

Comment: Can you clarify what you mean by "hex string"?

Comment: I am sending commands to an electronic device that can accept hex commands via serial or UDP. I believe, for one example, the 'play' command we are trying to send is "0xFF 0x05 0x01 0xFE". When I send through serial (using another device) it works ok, but not when I send through g_socket_send. When I send the above string through g_socket_send and monitor what is coming out of my program with a port sniffer, it appears to be sending the ASCII equivalent of my string as opposed to the hex value.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are sending *bytes*. You need to figure out what the other end expects, and build those bytes accordingly. Say, if your receiver wants binary data, then this might be it:

```
char buffer[4] = { 0xFF, 0x05, 0x01, 0xFE };
/* ... */
if ( g_socket_send( socket, buffer, 4, ... ) < 0 ) {
    /* handle error */
}
```